# IOS 9 Ipad kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802 ,how to solve this issue?

Tags: ios, ipad, ssl, server, ios9

When we call third party library , get the below issue.

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)  Error: An SSL error has occurred and
>   a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add bellow mentioned code to your info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>

<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>hiveage.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Started from ios9 you have to use https protocol.

If you cannot use https you will need to put a setting in your plist file to go around this.

Add an entry with a NSdictionary, then inside add a boolean, see this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Although Apple does not recommend to set NSAllowArbitaryLoads to YES. It is better to define specific domain exceptions in your .plist.

Comment: When i try u answers .i got this issue. actually i'm used third party library  .I don't know Sub Domain . how to solve this .NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9814)
 Error: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “cssnwebservices.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.